# Free US sales-tax lookup (per zip etc.)?

Tags: api, finance

I am creating a pricing program. I need to calculate the amounts according to the current tax list in the US (in various places).

I want to have a button 'Update taxes' in the administrative settings of the application, so when the user clicks it, it should download from somewhere the active tax amounts.

So I actually want to have a function `decimal GetTax(string zip)`.

Does anyone knows about a free downloadable xml, or RSS accessible or even a website that I can crawle in and get this info from?

Comment: Seems as though you're starting out with a built in limitation that your program will only calculate pricing for US customers. There are a lot of potential users who don't live in the US - or who do live in the US but do business internationally.

Comment: Which taxes are you looking for? There are lots of different kinds!

Comment: I am looking for the total sales-tax within only the US.

Comment: I asked a [similar question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/878/193) on [opendata stackexchange](https://opendata.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try http://www.telcotax.com/?

Comment: Really? Works fine for me.
Maybe this one? http://www.telcotax.com/Default.aspx

Comment: It's slow as hell!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of third-party solutions out there. Here is one:

http://www.avalara.com/Products/Integrations/Ecommerce?gclid=CI2CyKfuu6ECFZIU5wodtUWW_w

Comment: I slightly updated my question.

Comment: The above site has a free lookup service (limited to 50 lookups per month). 

The kind of info you are looking for is not easy to get - every state is different, and someone has to go through the work of aggregating all the info and putting it all in one place. I'll be very surprised if you find a completely free solution.

Comment: I don't find the free lookup, can you please provide a link?
I am sure I will have to do some homework, and I hope they're not going to change their structure so my homework is worthless. Do you know this service? are they reliable?

Answer (score 0):

try this http://www.taxrates.com